# How to make one list from the results of an for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have this script

```
for row in c:
    res = subprocess.Popen('bgpq3 -4 {} -m 24 -l {}'.format(row[5],row[2]), shell=True, universal_newlines=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = res.communicate()

    lines = []
    for line in stdout.split('\n')[1:10]:
        lines.append(line)
        print(lines)
```

Which results in:

```
   ['ip prefix-list 12414 permit 5.57.248.0/21']
   ['ip prefix-list 12414 permit 5.57.248.0/21', 'ip prefix-list 12414 permit 5.199.144.0/20']
   ['ip prefix-list 12414 permit 5.57.248.0/21', 'ip prefix-list 12414 permit 5.199.144.0/20', 'ip prefix-list 12414 permit 5.206.208.0/20']
```

I am using the append method to make one big list but I get many lists!
Any idea?

Comment: put your `print` out of the `for`.

Comment: And what about simply: `lines = stdout.split('\n')[1:10]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see the correct list is the last printed list. it is because you put your `print` function inside your loop and will print out the current list in all 
 iteration, so, remove the print from `for` body and put it out of the loop.

```
for line in stdout.split('\n')[1:10]:
    lines.append(line)
print(lines)
```